# Read unstructured CSV file into pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, preprocessor

I'd like to read CSV file composed of three columns, company number, ticker, business Description. The business description column contains lots of information of the company.

ex) Albemarle Corporation operates as a developer, manufacturer, and marketer of specialty chemicals that are designed to meet its customersâ€™ needs across a range of end markets worldwide.
The end markets that the company serves include energy storage, petroleum refining, consumer electronics, construction, automotive, lubricants, pharmaceuticals, crop protection and custom chemistry services.

When I use pd.read_CSV, it start to read description column after reading first and second column from the first row to last row.

What should I do?

[image: here is the result I got]

Comment: Can you please post what does your dataframe look like after reading the file and also what you actually expect?

Comment: The picture I posted was what i've got. I want to make third column as Description part. But description part appear at the end of the data frame.

Comment: The question still seems unclear, can you please post how exactly your CSV file looks like? and the full syntax along with parameters passed to `pf.read_csv()`